# Pseudocode to optimise profit

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I am currently working on a question and would like help in my thought process or correction in my code. I mainly have three parameters n people, maxweight, and items for my function. Items are in 2D lists representing ID, price, and weight. Eg. [[Item A, 20, 50], [Item B, 30, 60]].

I have to return a 2D list of items per n people with the idea that each person carries items optimised by price but in a fair distributed manner. It also cannot exceed the maxweight. So, if n is 3 then person 3 shouldn't be carrying only items priced at low prices while person 1 only carries items priced high, it should be even to a certain extent. For example, if n is 2 and items list is length of 6, the result of items carried for person 1 and 2 could be:

```
[[Item A, Item C, Item F], [Item B, Item E]]
```

where D is not added as it would exceed weight.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
def listofItems(n, maxweight, items):
    sort the 2d lists of items according to desc prices
    result = n * [[]] #creating empty list for result
    num = 0 
    
    while num is lesser than len(items):
        weight += items[num][2] #adding the weight first
        if weight is lesser than maxweight:
            for i in range n:
                if len(result[n]) is not num + 1:
                     append the item ID into result
                     num += 1
        else:
            weight -= items[num][2]
            num += 1
    return result
```

I dont think this works because the index will go out of range, and I'm not sure if this is the correct/best answer to this question. Any feedback or tips to improve would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the metrics of extent/fairness? max deviation, mean deviation or something else? Or may you choose any resonable enough?

Comment: @AskoldIlvento max price $ with the best fairness in item price distribution across all n people! There isnt an exact metrics stated but I would assume one would want a fair distribution as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is a combinatorial problem, it looks more complex than the knapsack problem.
If the numbers of items and people are low, you may try bruteforce (python looking pseudocode).

```
best_allocation = None
best_value = inf
for allocation in itertools.product(range(npeople), repeat=nitem):
    if check_allocation_is_feasible(allocation):
        value = count_allocation_metrics (allocation)
        if value < best_value:
            best_value = value
best_ allocation = allocation
```

If the numbers are moderate. You may try to turn the problem into an integer linear problem. Your constraints are linear. And the total price for each person is also linear. But metrics of fairness should be chosen carefully. Maximum may suit. If you take all differences between total costs for each person `ci - cj < k` minimizing k gives you a linear problem.

If the numbers are high you need a heuristic approach with reasonable complexity. I could suggest putting the next item to a person who can carry it but has minimal cost of already assigned items. Then you allocate all items you may try to locally improve the overall item allocation trying to swap items between two persons who totally carry the highest and lowerest sets of items. The last step can be repeated several times. And the whole procedure can be tried several times for different item orders to achieve different results.

---

**Bruteforce code**

```
import itertools
import numpy

npeople = 3
nitems = 5

numpy.random.seed(100)
capacities = numpy.random.randint(100, 200, npeople)
weights = numpy.random.randint(10, 100, nitems)
costs = numpy.random.randint(1, 10, nitems)


def check_allocation_is_admissible(allocation):
  burdens = [0]*npeople
  for item, preson in enumerate(allocation):
    burdens[preson] += weights[item]
    if burdens[preson] > capacities[preson]:
      return  False
  return True

def count_allocation_metrics(allocation):
  total_cost = [0]*npeople
  for item, preson in enumerate(allocation):
    total_cost[preson] += costs[item]

  max_deviation = 0
  for c1 in total_cost:
    for c2 in total_cost:
      max_deviation = max(max_deviation, c1 - c2)

  return max_deviation


best_allocation = None
best_value = numpy.inf

for allocation in itertools.product(range(npeople), repeat=nitems):
  #allocation has number of items dimension and each element denotes who carry corresponding item
  if check_allocation_is_admissible(allocation):
    value = count_allocation_metrics(allocation)
    if value < best_value:
        best_value = value
        best_allocation = allocation

print(best_allocation)
```

The answer will be like

```
(1, 0, 2, 1, 2)
```

that means that 0th item is assigned to 1th person, 1th item is assigned to 0th person etc. Your requested representation is different, but it should not be difficult to convert.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes I believe its an advanced question to the knapsack. I would like to attempt this solution in code function, would you be able to help me in translating this? Is best_allocation the empty list and what would the allocation properly refer to etc?

Comment: @nah fam, I updated the post with a valid pythonic code.